# break no rompe el ciclo de escucha del cliente en servidor al recibir palabra clave

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Tengo dos códigos: uno el servidor y otro el cliente:

**El servidor:**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9999))

s.listen(5)

print ("Servidor de Chat\n")


while True:

        print ("Esperando conexión...")
        sc, addr = s.accept()
        print ("Cliente conectado desde: ", addr)

        while True:
                recibido = sc.recv(1024)
                if recibido == "quit":
                        break
                print ("Recibido: ", recibido)

                nuestra_respuesta = "Hola cliente, yo soy el servidor."
                sc.send(nuestra_respuesta.encode('utf-8'))

print ("Adios")

sc.close()

s.close()
```

**El cliente:**

```
import socket

socket_cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_cliente.connect(("127.0.0.1", 999))

while True:
    mensaje = str(input(">> "))
    socket_cliente.send(mensaje.encode('utf-8'))

    recibido = socket_cliente.recv(1024)
    print("Recibido: ", recibido)

print ("Adios")

socket_cliente.close()
```

El problema esta en el servidor, en la linea 12:

```
if recibido == "quit":
    break
```

Al poner "quit" en el cliente no rompe con el bucle del servidor y continua su ejecución. El `break` no esta funcionando.

*Créditos a Barlan*

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que lo que envías por el sockets son bytes (sin codificación), la comparación  `if recibido == "quit":` nunca va a ser `True`. Ya que `"quit" != b"quit"`. Debes comparar con:

```
if recibido == b"quit":
```

o bién decodificar la cadena de bytes que te llega a UTF-8:

```
while True:

    print ("Esperando conexión...")
    sc, addr = s.accept()
    print ("Cliente conectado desde: ", addr)

    while True:
        recibido = sc.recv(1024)
        msg = recibido.decode("UTF-8")  # <<<<<<<<
        if msg == "quit":
            print("El cliente {} se desconectó.".format(addr))
            break
        print ("Recibido: ", msg)
```

Unos apuntes en cuanto al cliente:

- Tiene el puerto mal, debe ser 9999 (de acuerdo al servidor) y tienes 999.
- En Python 3 `input` ya retorna una cadena, el casting a `str` no es necesario (y en **Python 2 no se debería usar `input` para esto jamás**, para eso está `raw_input`).
- Deberías agregar otro condicional en el cliente para salir también cuando se envíe "quit".

Podría quedar algo así:

```
import socket

socket_cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_cliente.connect(("localhost", 9999))

while True:
    mensaje = input(">> ")
    socket_cliente.send(mensaje.encode('utf-8'))
    if mensaje == "quit":
        break
    recibido = socket_cliente.recv(1024)
    print("Recibido: ", recibido)

print ("Adios")

socket_cliente.close()
```

---

**Edición:**

Si quieres que el servidor se cierre también cuando el cliente mande la señal de "quit" entonces debes romper también el ciclo encargado de esperar y aceptar los clientes. Dado que `break` solo rompe el ciclo donde se encuentra anidado, puedes usar una variable de control en su lugar:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9999))
s.listen(1)
print ("Servidor de Chat\n")

run =  True
while run:

    print ("Esperando conexión...")
    sc, addr = s.accept()
    print ("Cliente conectado desde: ", addr)

    while run:
        recibido = sc.recv(1024)
        msg = recibido.decode("UTF-8")

        if msg == "quit":
            print("El cliente {} se desconectó.".format(addr))
            run = False 

        print ("Recibido: ", msg)
        nuestra_respuesta = "Hola cliente, yo soy el servidor."
        sc.send(nuestra_respuesta.encode('utf-8'))

print ("Adios")
s.close()
```

Pero dado que como es lógico solo vas a aceptar en este caso a un cliente, el primer `while` simplemente sobra:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9999))
s.listen(1)
print ("Servidor de Chat\n")
print ("Esperando conexión...")
sc, addr = s.accept()
print ("Cliente conectado desde: ", addr)

while True:
    recibido = sc.recv(1024)
    msg = recibido.decode("UTF-8")

    if msg == "quit":
        print("El cliente {} se desconectó.".format(addr))
        break

    print ("Recibido: ", msg)

    nuestra_respuesta = "Hola cliente, yo soy el servidor."
    sc.send(nuestra_respuesta.encode('utf-8'))

print ("Adios")
s.close()
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Ya corregi los fallos y ahora funciona.

Comment: Y podria salir del primer bucle while del servidor?

Comment: Porque al producirse un quit me retorna al perimer ciclo while.

Comment: Entonces el print("Adios") no sirve de nada

Comment: @telegrima al final de mi respuesta he añadido la edición respondiendo a tu duda. Ten en cuenta que en este caso solo esperas hasta que un cliente se conecte y cuando éste envie "quit" tanto cliente como servidor terminarán.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda